# pass variable from js to php using POST

Tags: php, jquery, post

Whay I can't pass a variable from js to php

```
 $("#btnpage").click(function(){
        path = $('#spantwrap').html();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'plus-page.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {'path': path},
            success: function() {
                console.log(path);
            }
        });
    location.href = 'plus-page.php';
    });
```

**plus-page.php**

```
<form id="form1" action="?" method="post">    
<input type="hidden" name="path" value="<?php echo $_POST['path'];?>" // line 46
</form>
```

Error: Undefined index: path on line 46...

Comment: Show your `$('#spantwrap')` html code.

Comment: You are sending a POST request to the server and in a success case you are redirecting to the same page, which results in a GET request, where `$_POST` is empty. With Ajax, you are doing a hidden call to the back-end and in the success handler you should manipulate the page and e.g. display the results on the page. You shouldn't forward to another page.

Comment: What do you get when print/alert path first and add html of spantwrap id?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3, see my update,pls

Comment: Remove `location.href = 'plus-page.php';`, as it will always give you an undefined index error. You are accessing `$_POST['path']` in a GET request.

Comment: @Jits, `console.log(path)` works fine. That's a short and simple html code.

Comment: What about ? var path = $('#spantwrap').html();

Comment: @Jits, `path` is a global ja variable, declared at the top of js file. It works fine inside js.

Comment: 1. Can you try moving path outside of the click then? 2. Does it work when defining value inside click directly? 3. Does it work when you directly pass path value in ajax?

Comment: I can see, you are not returning any value from ajax success :)

Comment: I dont' understand what do you want? You make post request by ajax, but why do you want use `location` to redirect and re-post this data?

Comment: @Victoray, i simply want to go on `plus-page.php` which is equipped with the variable `path`.

Comment: Create a hidden input in a html form. When you clicked, set path value to that input. After, make a submit by `.submit()` jquery. Ajax isn't a solution for your issue.

Comment: @Victoray, see my update, pls

Comment: Why do you want to make redirect `location.href` (it's a GET request, you cant send anything as POST input)? Sorry, but i must asking this question again. The ajax you created above, it is also a POST request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing variable - Undefined index error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802268/passing-variable-undefined-index-error)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$("#btnpage").click(function(){
    path = $('#spantwrap').html();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'plus-page.php',
        type: 'post',
        success: function() {
        location.href = 'plus-page.php?path=' + path;
        }
     });
});
```

so that you can use this?

```
<input type="hidden" name="path" value="<?php echo $_POST['path'];?>">
```

What would be the value of your path?

Comment: I need to use `POST` nad not `GET` procedure in this case

Comment: I edited the hidden element and changed from GET to POST. Still undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use form post method with this solution ??? ?

First Ajax post it completed when success: function called... In new window you doesn't have any post data, I don't know any solution post data by javascript to new window.. only one you can send data by GET request ..

You can see variable posted by ajax and open url by new window.. please use

> With out using ajax ,to achieve what you required.

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function(){
    var my_data = 'Test Test Tes';
        window.open('plus-page.php?my_data='+my_data);
  });
```

> plus-page.php

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_GET['my_data'])){
        $data=$_GET['my_data'];    
        echo $data;          
 }
?>
```