# passing variable - Undefined index error

Tags: javascript, php

I want to pass `path` variable from js to `plus-page.php` and then go to that page.

```
 $("#btnpage").click(function(){
        path = $('#spantwrap').html();
        console.log(path); // works, that's a simple html code.
        $.ajax({
            url: 'plus-page.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {'path': path},
            success: function() {
                console.log(path);
            }
        });
    location.href = 'plus-page.php';
    });
```

**plus-page.php**

```
<form id="form1" action="?" method="post">    
<input type="hidden" name="path" value="<?php echo $_POST['path'];?>" // line 46
</form>
```

Error: `Undefined index: path on line 46...`

Comment: no need for ajax if you are redirecting page just submit the form using php

Comment: Try: isset($_POST['path']) && $_POST['path'] ? $_POST['path'] : '';

Comment: You are now sending an Ajax POST call and loading that URL immediately after that via GET. You should either do something with the output of your Ajax call in the `success` callback, or just submit the form to that URL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801853/pass-variable-from-js-to-php-using-post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is of course to get rid of ajax call and just post your form to `plus-page.php` because it doesn't make any sense in current form

But if you really want to have this logic, i.e passing some variable to second page and redirect to that page later then you should keep the passed value in session and use it later on

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['path'])
{
    $_SESSION['path'] = $_POST['path'];

    // to stop only in case of AJAX call use the following line:
    // if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')

    die();
}
?>

<form id="form1" action="?" method="post">    
<input type="hidden" name="path" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['path'];?>" // line 46
</form>
```

Note that this DOESN'T make any sense if you want to redirect immediataly

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're redirecting immediately, and not passing along the variable in the redirection. Since you redirect immediately, the ajax call that's in-progress never really gets started and is terminated almost immediately.

Just remove your ajax call entirely and set the location like so:

```
location.href = "plus-page.php?path=" + encodeURIComponent(path);
```

...and use `$_GET['path']` instead of `$_POST['path']`.

Alternatively, if you *really* want to do the ajax call first, wait for it to complete before going to the new page:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'plus-page.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'path': path}, // Side note: The ' here are unnecessary (but harmless)
    success: function() {
        location.href = 'plus-page.php'; // You might or might not add path here as
                                         // above, it's unclear why you'd do the
                                         // ajax then redirect
        console.log(path);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$("#btnpage").click(function(){
    path = $('#spantwrap').html();
    console.log(path); // works, that's a simple html code.

    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var element1 = document.createElement("input"); 

    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "plus-page.php";   

    element1.value=path;
    element1.name="path";
    form.appendChild(element1);  

    document.body.appendChild(form);

    form.submit();
});
```

This creates a form, adds the path as an input to the form and submits the form.

Comment: I realised that the form presented in the code was for a different page and he seemed to be getting content from a span not a form :)